1990s children’s book about parallel universes where the protagonists cause Guy Fawkes' failure
I would have read it when I was around 10 in the mid- to late-90s.
I remember it being about a small group of kids. The idea is presented that every decision you make causes a new timeline or universe (multiverse) to split from the original timeline where the whole thing plays out with the other decision.
There's some main plot point where they're trying to save the world or solve a mystery and I’m fairly certain some choice they make causes the whole Guy Fawkes Parliament plot to fail in their current timeline.
I also think at least part of this takes place in
"modern day" England or London. Maybe even one of the kids is in a tunnel with the explosives and causes the plot to fail.  I seem to remember it having a depiction of several of the kids on the front.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where you say "a deprivation of several of the kids," what is that supposed to say?  Can you [edit] this to clarify?

I think this may be Witch Week by Diana Wynne Jones. The children live in a world with magic, but it turns out to be an unofficial offshoot of another world (ours) In their world, Guy Fawkes blew up the Houses of Parliament. A boy who is magicked so that nothing he says is true, is made to say this out loud. This makes it not true, and their world rejoins with ours.

I'm really curious now - once the worlds are rejoined, does our world gain magic, or does everyone originally from their world lose theirs?

It's not specifically stated, but our world didn't have any magic, and the offshoot had loads; so I suppose it averaged out.
